# tcpdump showing dbus adapters

Tags: tcpdump

Trying to start learning tcpdump.  However whenever I try to use it rather than giving me a list of adapters when using `tcpdump -nS`, I get:

```
tcpdump: WARNING: SIOCGIFADDR: dbus-system: No such device
tcpdump: packet printing is not supported for link type DBUS: use -w
```

From `tcpdump -D`:

```
1. dbus-system
2. dbus-session
```

From `tcpdump -w`:

```
tcpdump version 4.5.1
libpcap version 1.5.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to run `tcpdump` as root.**  Otherwise, `tcpdump -D` will not show all of the possible devices.

Then you need to specify the interface you wish to capture on, with `-i`:

```
tcpdump -i eth0
```

> If unspecified, `tcpdump` searches the system interface list for the lowest numbered, configured up interface (excluding loopback).

Comment: "You need to run tcpdump as root. Otherwise, tcpdump -D will not show all of the possible devices."  In particular, it will only show you the devices on which you can capture if you're *not* running as root, which may not include your network devices.  If that's the case, you won't be able to capture traffic without running tcpdump as root.

Comment: Thanks, now I feel stupid.  Forgot it had to run as root